# Adding javascript after click event of the refiners (display template question)

Tags: 2013, search, display-template, refiner

I want to execute my javascript code postrender of my refiners. I have done that by using this:

```
ctx.OnPostRender = [];    
ctx.OnPostRender.push(ctx, function () {
        mycode();
    });
```

This all happens within my refiner display template.

However, this will only cause my code to run once. As I want to run my code after each "refresh", I need to have some kind of event I can use instead.

Anyone know where I can find such a thing?

Comment: Have you tried with AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function () {     // do something
});

Comment: No difference :(